# How to validate mark_from as after mark_to in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I am using Laravel-5.8 for my project.

I am familiar with after:Date for validating dates

However, I want to validate that mark_to must be greater than mark_from

Rules Request Validate

```
        'mark_from' => [
            'required',
            'numeric',
            'min:0',
            'max:500', 
            new AllowedGrade,
        ], 
        'mark_to' => [
            'required',
            'numeric',
            'min:1',
            'max:500',   
            'after:mark_from',
        ],
```

When I applied the above in Rules Request, it's not doing the validation.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: mark_from and mark_to are integers ?

Comment: @N69S - Yes, numeric. See it in the validation

Comment: the use greater than `gt:fmark_from`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use greater than rule

```
    'mark_from' => [
        'required',
        'numeric',
        'min:0',
        'max:500', 
        new AllowedGrade,
    ], 
    'mark_to' => [
        'required',
        'numeric',
        'min:1',
        'max:500',   
        'gt:mark_from',
    ],
```